# Uniswap (pair/liquidity) creation in contrat constructor. How is it possible?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, pancakeswap

Many of the new tokens create pair on Pancakeswap/Uniswap at the token constructor.

I understand that the token constructor runs when the contract is created.

```
constructor() public {
   
    IPancakeRouter02 _pancakeswapV2Router =
        IPancakeRouter02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);      
    pcsV2Pair = IPancakeFactory(_pancakeswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(
        address(this),
        _pancakeswapV2Router.WETH()
    );
    pcsV2Router = _pancakeswapV2Router;

   
}
```

This example is from this token: https://bscscan.com/address/0xfd78aaed1e3f2d06dbde9510c6dc14112eca896d#code

Are they creating the pair with zero liquidity, does that mean that anyone with a ridiculous amount of money can buy all the tokens?

For what purpose is the pair created in the constructor, is it not better to create the pair by manually entering the liquidity in Uniswap or Pancakeswap?